# JMeter burst traffic shaping

Tags: jmeter, web-traffic, trafficshaping

I want to run the following test for my webapp:

- Client should use T threads
- Client should generate R requests per second (rps). Traffic should **not** be uniform. Instead, the requests should be generated in bursts of X items,  with X > R, with each burst occurring as soon as possible.

So if T=40, X = 10,000 and R = 200:

- At t0, the client attempts to to send 10,000 requests as fast as possible, using 40 threads.
- After successfully sending the first 10,000 batch, the client waits until t1 = t0 + 50 sec (X/R). If it takes longer that 50 sec to send the first batch, an error is generated.
- At t1, the client attempts to send the next 10,000 batch, etc

Can this be simulated with an existing JMeter configuration or plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not have two groups of users, one setup to run a steady background load (your 200 tps) and then the other using an interval, one that matches your burst rate, set with a Constant Throughput Timer. If you add a Loop Controller to the burst group then you can generate large numbers of calls in staggered bursts.

Then you just need to set the loop and thread counts as required.